# Linux command for moving, merging and renaming duplicates

Tags: linux, software-rec, deduplication

I am trying to move directories (with sub-directories and files) to another directory. With `mv` some folders are not merging because the same directory exists with files. This is no good because even if the files are more recent in the source directories they are being deleted upon the move.

I need a command that will:

1. move directories that do not exist in the destination directory, and;
2. merge directories that already exists in the destination directory, and;
3. rename any duplicate files (eg: `file.txt` already exists, renames the source file to `file(1).txt`)

I have not been able to find anything that can handle all of this.

*Edit*

I have tried using the following command:

```
mv -u [source] [destination]
```

It only moves the directories that do not exist in the destination, and I believe discards any that are duplicated with content. So, any newer files from the source directory are lost upon moving. Instead, these directories should merge and rename any duplicate files. Hope I have explained this well enough.

P.S. This would work best if written in a terminal command, I am not experienced with creating scripts.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I eventually used just to accomplish what I needed. It's not perfect but with moving that many directories this took care of 99% of the move/merge.

First, I used 'mv' to move all the directories to the new destination that didn't exist there. Each of the destination folders are labeled as follows, "a, b, c...". I wanted each source directory starting with an "A" to move to its respective destination directory ("a").

```
mv -u /[source directory]/A* /[destination directory]/a && mv -u /[source directory]/B* /[destination directory]/b && so on and so on...
```

This did not move all of the directories because a % of them already existed in the destination. So next, I ran `rsync` very similarly to the above command:

```
rsync --progress --remove-source-files -arvu /[source directory]/A* /[destination directory]/a && rsync --progress --remove-source-files -arvu /[source directory]/B* /[destination directory]/b && and so on and so on...
```

I had destination directories from A-Z and 0-9 so I just ran these commands over and over changing the letters and numbers and combining these commands with `&&`. It did the job but it's a lengthy commands as I am sure you can imagine.

To finish it off I ran the following command:

```
find . -type d -empty -print -delete
```

This took care of the empty directories left behind by rsync. Could this have all been done with just rsync? I don't know. I'm a rookie and learning something new here.

Like I said, not perfect but it worked for me and I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

The files may not be going where you think. I recommend using the `-t` or `-T` option of `mv`.